# Is this dictionary or hashtable in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

The following code is from ngrx example.

What this declaration will do? Is this equivalent to dictionary or hashtable in C#?

`let typeCache: { [label: string]: boolean } = {};`

The original code:

```
let typeCache: { [label: string]: boolean } = {};

export function type<T>(label: T | ''): T {
  if (typeCache[<string>label]) {
    throw new Error(`Action type "${label}" is not unique"`);
  }

  typeCache[<string>label] = true;

  return <T>label;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about the C# equivalence, but what it means in typescript is a regular javascript object with boolean properties, and it's referred as [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).
The keys can only be strings or numbers, this won't compile:

```
let typeCache: { [label: Date]: boolean } = {}; // error: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'
```

Examples of how a value would look like:

```
type Indexable = { [label: string]: boolean };

let typeCache1: Indexable = { a: true, b: false };
let typeCache2: Indexable = { a: true, b: "string" }; // error: Type '{ a: true; b: "string"; }' is not assignable to type 'Indexable'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is map in javascript, a simple key/value map. for details, refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: No, he isn't asking about a `Map`, he's using a regular object.